# Two threads updating the same object, will it work? java

Tags: java, concurrency, thread-safety

I have two methods as follows:

```
class A{
  void method1(){
    someObj.setSomeAttribute(true);
    someOtherObj.callMethod(someObj);
  }
  void method2(){
    someObj.setSomeAttribute(false);
    someOtherObj.callMethod(someObj);
  }
}
```

where in another place that attribute is evaluated:

```
class B{
  void callMethod(Foo someObj){
    if(someObj.getAttribute()){
        //do one thing

    } else{
        //so another thing
    }
  }
}
```

Note that `A.method1` and `A.method2` are updating the attribute of the same object. If those 2 methods are run in 2 threads, will this work or will there be unexpected results?

Comment: "*will there be unexpected results*" Whether it's unexpected or not depends on what you expect.

Comment: Will it work yes, will there be unexpected results, most probably.  You need to look at concurrency theory and understand things like race conditions. You can't guarantee the order in which the two threads will execute and you will need consider what that means if the order changes.  You also need to consider how the memory model of the JVM works, as modifying the state of the object might not be "updated" to other threads until some point in the future (that's quite vague and some one can descibe it better, but you'd want to investigate things like `volatile`)

Answer (score 0):

Will there be unexpected results? Yes, guaranteed, in that if you modify things you wouldn't want to have an impact on your app (such as the phase of the moon, the current song playing in your winamp, whether your dog is cuddling near the CPU, if it's the 5th tuesday of the month, and other such things), that may have an effect on behaviour. Which you don't want.

What you've described is a so-called violation of the java memory model: The end result is that any java implementation is free to return any of multiple values and nevertheless, that VM is operating properly according to the java specification. Even if it does so seemingly arbitrarily.

As a general rule, each thread gets an unfair coin. Unfair, in that it will try to mess with you: It'll flip correctly every time when you test it out, and then in production, and only when you're giving a demo to that crucial customer, it'll get ya.

Every time it reads to or writes from any field, it will flip this mean coin. On heads, it will use the actual field. On tails, it will use a local copy it made.

That's oversimplifying the model quite a bit, but it's a good start to try to get your head around how this works.

The way out is to force so-called 'comes before' relationships: What java will do, is ensure that what you can observe matches these relationships: If event A is defined as having a comes-before relationship vs. event B, then anything A did will be observed, exactly as is, by B, guaranteed. No more coin flips.

Examples of establishing comes-before relationships involve using `volatile`, `synchronized`, and any methods that use these things internally.

NB: Of course. if your `setSomeAttribute` method, which you did not paste, includes some comes-before-establishing act, then there's no problem here, but as a rule a method called `setX` will not be doing that.

An example of one that doesn't:

```
class Example {
  private String attr;

  public void setAttr(String attr) {
    this.attr = attr;
  }
}
```

some examples of ones that do:

- Let's say method `B.callMethod` is executed in the same thread as `method1` - then you are guaranteed to at least observe the change method1 made, though it's still a coin flip (whether you actually see what method2 did or not). What would not be possible is seeing the value of that attribute before either method1 or method2 runs, because code running in a single thread has comes-before across the entire run (any line that is executed before another in the same thread has a comes-before relationship).
- The set method looks like:

```
class Example {
  private String attr;
  private final Object lock = new Object();

  public void setAttr(String attr) {
    synchronized (lock) {
      this.attr = attr;
    }
  }

  public String getAttr() {
    synchronized (lock) {
      return this.attr;
    }
  }
}
```

Now the get and set ops lock on the same object, that's one of the ways to establish comes-before. Which thread got to a lock first is observable behaviour; if method1's set got there before B's get, then you are guaranteed to observe method1's set.

More generally, sharing state between threads is extremely tricky and you should endeavour not do so. The alternatives are:

- Initialize all state before starting a thread, then do the job, and only when it is finished, relay all results back. Fork/join does this.
- Use a messaging system that has great concurrency fundamentals, such as a database, which has transactions, or message queue libraries.
- If you must share state, try to write things in terms of the nice classes in j.u.concurrent.

Comment: Yes, so instead of updating the same object, making a clone of it and passing 2 different objects would work right?

Comment: Sure; if any object is observed and changed solely from within a single thread, trivially you won't have any problems.

Answer (score 0):

I assume what you expected is when you call `A.method1`, `someObj.getAttribute()` will return `true` in `B.callMethod`, when you call `A.method2`, `someObj.getAttribute()` will return `false` in `B.callMethod`.

Unfortunately,this will not work. Because between the line `setSomeAttribute` and `callMethod`,other thread may have change the value of the attribute.

If you are only use the attribute in `callMethod`,why not just pass the attribute instead of the `Foo` object. Code as follow:

```
class A{
  void method1(){
    someOtherObj.callMethod(true);
  }
}
class B{
  void callMethod(boolean flag){
    if(flag){
        //do one thing
    } else{
        //so another thing
    }
  }
}
```

If you must use `Foo` as the parameter, what you can do is to make `setAttribute` and `callMethod` atomic.
The easiest way to achieve it is to make it synchronized.Code as follow:

```
  synchronized void method1(){
    someObj.setSomeAttribute(true);
    someOtherObj.callMethod(someObj);
  }
  synchronized void method2(){
    someObj.setSomeAttribute(false);
    someOtherObj.callMethod(someObj);
  }
```

But this may have bad performance, you can achieve it with some more fine-grained lock.